# How does the Hopf map generate $\pi_3(S^2)$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, hopf-fibration, higher-homotopy-groups

I have been studying the Hopf fibration which is an example of a map from $S^3$ to $S^2$. It is a member of $\pi_3(S^2)$ and shows that this group is non-trivial. It can be shown using a long exact sequence applied to the Hopf fibration that $\pi_3(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

However, the set of notes I am using to learn this material ([here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~hutching/teach/215b-2011/homotopy.pdf)) then claims that the Hopf map is a generator of this group. Furthermore, the Hopf invariant, which is a sort of linking number of the preimages of distinct points can be used to define this isomorphism with $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

I fail to see how the hopf map generates $\pi_3(S^2)$. Specifically, I would like to know how you can compose the hopf map to generate maps with higher hopf invariant that make up this integer-like group structure. It would be really helpful to explicitly see this in action (i.e. pointers on how to writ this out using elementary algebra).

Note: I have a Chemistry background so my understanding of Mathematics is quite basic though I am willing to learn.

Comment: "shows that this group is not null-homotopic" -- that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: You can think of a $3$-sphere as a cube with boundary identified to a point. You can compose two maps of the $3$-sphere by gluing two cubes along one of their boundaries. When you look at the Hopf invariant, it obviously adds, since it is the linking number of the preimage in one cube plus the linking number of the preimage in the other cube,

Comment: @JohnHughes Corrected.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I think I understand what you mean but it would help a lot to know how to write this composition out explicitly. E.g. the Hopf map can be written as $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \rightarrow (2(x_1x_2+x_3x_4), 2(x_1x_4-x_2x_3), (x_1^2 + x_3^2 - x_2^2 - x_4^2))$. How would I compose this algebraically to form a map with Hopf invariant $2$?

Comment: What is your question: Whether the Hopf-map $h : S^3 \to S^2$ generates $\pi_3(S^2)$ or how the multiples $n [h] \in \pi_3(S^2)$ look like?

Comment: @PaulFrost The latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we write $S^3$ as the set of all pairs $(z, w)$ of complex numbers with $|z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1$, and write $S^2$ as the complex plane plus a point at infinity. The the Hopf map is just
$$
(z, w) \mapsto \frac{z}{w}.
$$
(The formula you gave is, I believe, pretty much the same as this, but after stereographic projection from the plane to 3-space.

To get a degree-two map, we can simply take a degree two map from $S^2$ to $S^2$ and compose. In particular, we can define
$$
H_2(z, w)= \left(\frac{z}{w}\right)^2
$$
and more generally, define
$$
H_k(z, w)= \left(\frac{z}{w}\right)^k
$$
for every integer $k$. The map $k \mapsto H_k$ defines an injective (use the Hopf invariant!) map from $\Bbb Z$ to $\pi_3(S^2)$. And $H_1 = H$ is a generator, because the Hopf invariant for *that* map is a $1$, which is a unit.

Comment: You should be careful about the distinction between precomposing and postcomposing with degree m maps of spheres in this context. Given a map in $\pi_k (S^n)$, it is not generally true that precomposing by a degree m map is the same as postcomposing. In particular, for the Hopf map postcomposition by a map of degree -1 has no effect even though the Hopf map is not its own inverse. Probably safer to just precompose by a degree n map, as that is how addition in the homotopy groups is defined.

Comment: Though it always agrees after a suspension.

Comment: Sorry for taking a while to thank you. I have been familiarising myself with the consequences of your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The Hopf map is the projection map of a bundle $ S^1 \rightarrow S^3 \rightarrow S^2$. From this fiber bundle we get a long exact sequence. This sequence splits up into exact sequences $0 \rightarrow \pi_n (S^3) \rightarrow \pi_n (S^2) \rightarrow 0$ for $n>2$ because the higher homotopy groups of a circle vanish. In particular, this isomorphism is coming from post composition with the Hopf map. Specializing to $n=3$, this isomorphism must take any generator of $\pi_3 (S^3)$ to a generator of $\pi_3 (S^2)$. Since a generator of the first is the identity, the Hopf map must generate $\pi_3 (S^2)$.

Comment: The question explicitly says that OP knows all this, but wants an explicit description of the multiples of the Hopf map. Your answer seems ... baffling, as if you hadn't read the question.

Comment: If you read the question carefully, he says that he knows this argument proves there is an isomorphism. He then says he’d like an argument as to why the Hopf map generates the group. This is what I addressed in my answer. Hope that debaffles you.