# Continuity of map $SU(2)\to \mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactification

Let $Y:=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ be the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$. Define

Consider the map
$$\Phi: SU(2)\to Y: \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \frac{b}{a}$$
where we define $b/0:= \infty$ for every $b\in \mathbb{C}$.

I want to show that this map is continuous. I tried the following:

Indeed, if $W\subseteq Y$ is an open subset, we distinguish two cases. In the first case, $\infty \notin W$, but then
$$\Phi^{-1}(W)= \Psi^{-1}(W)$$
where $$\Psi: \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\c & d\end{pmatrix}\in SU(2): a \ne 0\right\}\to \mathbb{C}: \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\c & d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \frac{b}{a}$$ so by continuity of $\Psi$ we see that $\Psi^{-1}(W)$ is open in the domain of $\Psi$, which itself is open in $SU(2)$. Therefore, $\Psi^{-1}(W)$ is open in $SU(2)$.

In the second case, $\infty \in W$. Then I couldn't finish.

Any input is highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you knew coordinates around $\infty$ in $Y$? That would make the question easy.

Comment: @LeeMosher No I don't think so. I was approaching this without differential geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exploit that $SU(2)$ has the topology of the three-sphere:

Since the determinant of each matrix in $SU(2)$ must be one we know that
$ad-cb=1\,.$ Also, since each matrix is orthonormal, we can write it as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}u+iv & -w+ix\\w+ix&u-iv \end{pmatrix}
$$
with $u^2+v^2+w^2+x^2=1\,.$ This means that $u^2+v^2\le 1$ and $w^2+x^2\le 1\,.$ In other words, it is not possible that any of $a,b,c,d$ diverges to $\infty\,.$

Now let $a_n\to 0$ and $b_n\to b\in\mathbb C\,,c_n\to c\in\mathbb C\,,d_n\to d\in\mathbb C\,.$ Since $(d_n)$ cannot diverge it follows from $a_nd_n-c_nb_n=1$ that
$$
c_nb_n\to 1\,.
$$
Since $c_n$ cannot diverge it is not possible that $b_n\to 0\,.$ This implies
$$
\frac{b_n}{a_n}\to\infty=\Phi\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)\,.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you elaborate a bit on the last line? Don't you need to make this rigorous with the definition of the one-point compactification? $\infty$ is a formal symbol here.

Comment: I showed that $b/a$ does not converge in $\mathbb C$ despite $a\to 0$ and (of course) $b$ converging to some value in $\mathbb C\,.$ The only possibility then is that $b/a$ converges to whatever symbol you have chosen to compactify $\mathbb C\,.$

Comment: I agree, if it is convergent. Why is it convergent?

Comment: I slightly changed the reasoning using sequences. The idea stays the same. "I agree, if it is convergent. Why is it convergent?" What is "it" ?

Comment: @Kurt.G You show that $b_n/a_n$ does not converge in $\mathbb{C}$, so if it convergent in the compactification, its limit is $\infty$. But why is it convergent in the compactification?

Comment: Non convergence can mean two things: a) that there is a non convergent (in $\mathbb C$) subsequence. Then it does of course not converge at all. In particular not in a compactification. b) (our case) every subsequence diverges. Compactification is nothing else than saying that sequences with property (b) converge in $\mathbb C\,\cup$ some symbol.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your assistance. I clearly have some thinking to do!

Comment: Ok, I think I convinced myself. What do you think about the following argument? Suppose that $a_n \to 0$. We show that $b_n/a_n \to \infty$. If this is not the case, there is an open neighborhood $W$ of $\infty$ and a subsequence $\{b_{n_k}/a_{n_k}\}_k\subseteq W^c$. But by definition of the one-point compactification, $\mathbb{C}\setminus W$ is compact, and thus the subsequence $\{b_{n_k}/a_{n_k}\}$ has a further subsequence that is convergent in $\mathbb{C}$. This is impossible, since $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n \to b$.

Comment: Sounds good. BTW the map $\Phi$ is the very famous [Hopf map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409088/how-does-the-hopf-map-generate-pi-3s2) about which you should read as much as you can.